# How can i change imagebutton background on onclick

Tags: android-button

I have image button and i want to change **button's background image** it when i pressed button. At first i have **green tick logo** and when i pressed image button that **green tick logo**  should changed into **red tick logo**. And if i pressed it again it should change into **green tick logo**. And again i pressed it , it should change again into **red tick logo** and repeat like that when i pressed it again. Help me (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var clicked = 0
$("#button").click(function() {
  if (clicked == 0) {
    $(this).css("background", "url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm19_RGu6ZbKhn_uryzGqZLIldxuLIYX-m6A&usqp=CAU) no-repeat");
    clicked = 1;
  } else {
    $(this).css("background", "url(https://lesspestcontrol.com.au/wp-content/uploads/green-tick.png) no-repeat");
    clicked = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
.button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(https://lesspestcontrol.com.au/wp-content/uploads/green-tick.png) no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="Search" class="button" />
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE: I have made the button big, so that it can fit in the images.